# grep finding ipv4 as words instead of lines

Tags: grep, regular-expression, ip-address

I have to find the ipv4 in a file.The problem is if there are other words on the same line as the IP the script wont print it.Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash


if [ -e ip.txt ]
then
    grep -E '^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$' ip.txt
else
    echo "file not found"
fi
```

Now if I have something like this the script wont print the IP:

```
198.54.34.6 text
```

Comment: Is the sample input you provide representative of all permutations? i.e. will the IP address always be the first word of the line? If not, please add any other input permutations that are possible, by editing your question.

Comment: Change it to `grep -Eo` (`-o` for only match) and rid the `$` on the end of it, like this: `grep -Eo '^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])' ip.txt` Like Prvt_Yadv's solution below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `^` and `$` from the command and use `-o` flag of grep command i.e.:

```
grep -Eo '(^| )(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])($|[[:space:]])'
```

Example:

```
echo 'some text 198.54.34.6 and test' | grep -Eo '(^| )(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])($|[[:space:]])'
```

output is:

```
 198.54.34.6
```

It will give spaces also try removing them using `tr`, like `command1 | tr -d " "`.

Comment: But that would match the `1.1.168.192` in `1.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa.` or `1.14.2.90` in `xserver-common_1.14.2.901-2_all.deb` for instance. The OP mentions trying to find *words*.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I think the `w` flag will work.

Comment: It wouldn't for the first example as `.` is not a word character. It depends on what the OP's data may contain that we wouldn't want to be included. If there may be things like version numbers or SNMP OIDs, then `-w` wouldn't prevent them from being mistakenly considered as containing IP addresses. If there's not then `-w` might be find. `grep -w '[0-9.]{7,}'` may also be enough depending on what the data may contain.

Comment: but how about `!2.2.1.2` ? by using `-w` this is still a valid ip

Comment: @RobertDumbrava see the edit.

Answer (score 3):

`^` and `$` match respectively at the beginning and end of the line, so lines with those IP addresses are only matched if the IP address is both at the beginning and end of the line, that is if the IP address *is* the whole line.

Now, if you want to match on lines that contain an IP address as a whole *word*, where *words* are blank-delimited, you could use:

```
d='[01234567890]'
n="($d|[123456789]$d|1$d$d|2[01234]$d|25[012345])"
grep -E "(^|[[:blank:]])$n\.$n\.$n\.$n([[:blank:]]|\$)" ip.txt
```

(here also replacing those `[0-9]` with `[0123456789]` as `[0-9]` often matches a lot more than just 0123456789).

Note that `grep` outputs the *lines* that match. If you want to only output parts of the lines, you'd need to use things like `sed` or `perl` instead (stream editors), or use some non-standard extensions of some `grep` implementations like the `-o` of GNU `grep`.

Here using negative look-around operators (`(?<!\H)` meaning *"provided it's not preceded by a non-blank"*, `(?!\H)` same but looking forward instead of behind, `(?1)` recalls the RE in the first `(...)` group, all perl-like operators enabled with `-P`:

```
grep -Po '(?<!\H)(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]\d|\d)\.(?1)\.(?1)\.(?1)(?!\H)' ip.txt
```

Which would be an equivalent of:

```
perl -lne 'print for
  /(?<!\H)(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]\d|\d)\.(?1)\.(?1)\.(?1)(?!\H)/g'
```

Comment: You should try testing your answers, none of these ideas worked for me.

Comment: @A.Danischewski you're right, it was pretty sloppy of me. It should be better now.

Answer (score 2):

To print only the IPv4's you could extract what is matched with the `-o` option to grep.

As a simpler example, you can do:

```
$ echo "this is a simple test to extract 123.234.34.5 as an IP" | 
       grep -o '[0-9.]*'

123.234.34.5
```

But that will fail to **precisely** match one IPv4.

To match an IP is somewhat complex with a regex. A regex do not understand numeric ranges, only text. We can match one numeric 0-255 value with (a regex that ignore spaces and comments):

```
25[012345]                       | # the numers 250 - 255 or
2[01234](?P<digit>[0123456789])  | # 200 - 249 or
1(?&digit){2}                    | # 100 - 199 or
#0?                                 # Allow leading zero
[1-9](?&digit)                   | #  10 -  99 or
#0{0,2}                             # Allow leading zeros
(?&digit)                          #   0 - 9
```

Remove the first column comments to include leading zeros.

To avoid the repetition of `[0-9]`, to use explicit numeric ranges (avoid matching numbers in other languages) and to give a name to each matching group we can use "Named Capture Groups" from PCRE's:

```
(?P<byte>                             # Define this as one full byte value.
25[012345]                          | # the numers 250 - 255 or
2[01234](?P<digit>[0123456789])     | # 200 - 249 or
1(?&digit){2}                       | # 100 - 199 or
#0?                                    # Allow leading zero
[1-9](?&digit)                      | #  10 -  99 or
#0{0,2}                               # Allow leading zeros
(?&digit)                             #   0 - 9
)                                     # close one full byte definition
```

Then we just need to repeat the use of the byte definition with a leading dot `(\.(?&byte)){3}` three more times and some leading and trailing markers as [shown in this link](https://regex101.com/r/c0io3w/1)

The leading and trailing markers could be simpler "word boundaries" (`\b`) if that is what is needed as [shown in this other link](https://regex101.com/r/GbphxT/1)

In the shell, with grep PCRE regex, the command could be written as:

```
$ grep -oP '(?xm)(?<=^|[^01234567890.])(?P<byte>25[012345]|2[01234](?P<digit>[0123456789])|[01]?(?&digit){1,2})(\.(?&byte)){3}(?=[^01234567890.]|$)' <<<"$a"
1.2.3.4
11.22.33.44
123.234.34.5
1.1.192.168
123.234.34.123
123.234.34.123
1.2.3.255
255.255.255.255
1.1.168.192
1.14.2.90
1.2.3.4
```

Given that the test string contains:

```
$ a='1.2.3.4
11.22.33.44
123.234.34.5
1.1.192.168
text 123.234.34.123 more text
text123.234.34.123more text
1.2.3.255
1.2.3.256
255.255.255.255
256.2.3.4
1123.234.34.123
123.234.34.1235
.123.234.34.123
123.234.34.123.
not 1.1.168.192 in 1.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa.
not 1.14.2.90 in xserver-common_1.14.2.901-2_all.deb
1.2.3.4'
```

Answer (score 1):

This regex will grab the ip address and is a fairly accurate regex for IPv4 addresses, `grep -P` turns on PCRE regex engine and `-o` only returns the matching text:

```
grep -Po '\b((?:25[0-5]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[1][0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[1][0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])\b' ip.txt
```

For an explanation of this regex see this: https://regexr.com/4kjg4

```
25[0-5]          | # 250 - 255 
[2][0-4][0-9]    | # 200 - 249 
[1][0-9]{2}      | # 100 - 199 
[1-9][0-9]       | #  10 - 99
[0-9]            | #   0 - 9
```

Comment: The OP already has a regexp to match quad-decimal IPv4 addresses (yours also include some octal-based ones like `010.010.010.010`, another wording for google's `8.8.8.8` but doesn't allow `0377.0377.0377.0377` as an equivalent of `255.255.255.255`). They're asking about how to find IP addresses **as words** in the input.

Comment: Updated, now it grabs only IPv4 words.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas It [is known](https://web.archive.org/web/20061206211851/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/115388) that interpreting IPv4 dotted addresses as octal leads to problems and there is known use of full 3 digits (with leading zeros) [in RFCs](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-main-ipaddr-text-rep-02)

Comment: @Isaac `[Page 7]   A 32-bit IPv4 address is divided into four octets.  Each octet is represented numerically in decimal, using the minimum possible number of digits (leading zeroes are not used, except in the case of 0 itself).  The four encoded octets are given most-significant first, separated by period characters.`

Comment: @Isaac  `IPv4address = d8 "." d8 "." d8 "." d8

        d8          = DIGIT               ; 0-9
                    / %x31-39 DIGIT       ; 10-99
                    / "1" 2DIGIT          ; 100-199
                    / "2" %x30-34 DIGIT   ; 200-249
                    / "25" %x30-35        ; 250-255`

Comment: @A.Danischewski You are quoting from the link **I provided**. I know what it says. There is general consensus that an IP has **four** numbers, that those numbers should be understood as decimal numbers (so, no octal or hexadecimal numbers) but there is no consensus about the leading zeros. That is one of the reasons that that RFC is a **draft** not an **standard**. Following the motto ""Be conservative in what you send, be liberal in what you accept", leading zeros may be allowed, but should never be understood to mean octal numbers.